# Xamarin forms Stop screen shot and record in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have xamarin forms app and need to prevent user from take screen shot or record screen
these implemented for android using these:
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
is there any we to do these for ios

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+prevent+screen+capture+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -1):

Like Jason said, you could find more information in Google. You could try the code below for ios to blur or hide the screenshot taken, to hide sensitive information. I hope this would be helpful for you.

A easy way is to set a blur when the AppDelegate calls OnResignActivation.

```
UIVisualEffectView _blurWindow = null;

public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
{
base.OnActivated(application);

_blurWindow?.RemoveFromSuperview();
_blurWindow?.Dispose();
_blurWindow = null;
}

public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
{
base.OnResignActivation(application);

using (var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.FromStyle(UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark))
{
    _blurWindow = new UIVisualEffectView(blurEffect)
    {
        Frame = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Bounds
    };
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.AddSubview(_blurWindow);
 }
}
```

I use Dark here. You could change the blur effect to Light, Regular or any of the other options listed.